# Negative deviance explained by GAM with betareg in R

Tags: r, mgcv, beta-regression

I am fitting the following model in "mgcv" package in R using option `family=betar` to predict a percentage cover response variable (`cyano %`):

```r
    g6 = gam(cyano/100 ~ s(SEGLOWFLOW) + s(SEGJANAIRT) + 
             s(LOCHAB) + s(LOCSED) + s(T2PastoralHeavy) + 
             s(SEDO) + s(USDAYSRAIN) + s(USAVGSLOPE) + 
             s(USHARDNESS), data=nati1, 
             family = betar(link='logit'))
```

I get the following warning message:

```r
    Warning message:
    In object$family$saturated.ll(G$y, wts, theta) :
      saturated likelihood may be inaccurate
```

The summary output gives me negative explained deviance values:

```r
    R-sq.(adj) =  0.0871   Deviance explained = -29.9%
    -REML = -2370.5  Scale est. = 1         n = 463
```

Although the diagnostics plots (`gam.check`) look fine and the predictions make sense, I am worried about the warning message and the negative deviance explained value.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried fixing some mistakes, but I am not sure whether you are using `betareg` anywhere. You do use `family=betar`, though. Please check the accuracy of your post and pardon if my edit might have introduced any new mistakes.

Comment: Great, thanks heaps. I only used betar family in the mgcv library.

Comment: I'm running into the same question. Is it just that REML and dev.explained don't give sensible values with `betar` ?

Comment: Does your response variable contain 0's or 1's? If so, you likely need to increase `eps` within `betar()`.

Comment: @jatalah did you end up sorting out what was causing this warning message?  I'm running into the same thing.